# Matplotlib, plotly, is displaying the graph as single line when adding trace

Tags: dataframe, plotly.js

I am trying to add a super trend indicator to the plotly graph, but it is making the graph as single line, I dont know what is going, on  I am bit new to python.and data frames.

````
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
import pandas_ta as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import time

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["crypto_data"]
db=mydb.all_data

db = pd.DataFrame(list(db.find()))

db['rsi14']=db.ta.rsi(14)

db.ta.ha(open='open', high='high', low='low', close='close', append=True)

db['sup']=ta.supertrend(high=db['HA_high'], low=db['HA_low'], close=db['HA_close'], period=7, multiplier=3)['SUPERT_7_3.0']
db['sup'].fillna(0, inplace=True)


fig= go.Figure(go.Candlestick(x=db['date'],
         open=db.HA_open,                        
         high=db.HA_high,
         low= db.HA_low,
         close=db.HA_close,
         showlegend=False))
fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=db['date'],
                         y=db['sup'],
                         opacity=0.7,
                         line=dict(color='blue', width=2),
                        name='sup'))
fig.show()
```

`

[after adding trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLMzh.png)[Without adding trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chytm.png)

I tried converting NaN values on 'sup' to 0, but still the issue is same.
````